# How to inject a Drone instance without managing its lifecycle?

Tags: arquillian-drone, graphene2

I have a Graphene Page Object.

```
@Location("/page")
public class MyPage {

    @Drone
    private WebDriver driver;

    // page methods using the driver

}
```

And a Test Class that uses the page object.

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Test
    public void test(@InitialPage MyPage page) {
        // use page & assert stuff
    }

    @Test
    public void anotherTest(@InitialPage MyPage page) {
        // use page & assert stuff even harder
    }

}
```

Now, I've decided that MyTest should use method scoped Drone instances. So I add...

```
public class MyTest {

    @Drone
    @MethodLifecycle
    private WebDriver driver;
```

Now when I run the test I get two browsers and all tests end with errors. Apparently this lifecycle management is treated as a qualifier too.

Yes, adding `@MethodLifecycle` in MyPage too helps. But this is not a solution - a page shouldn't care about this and should work in any WebDriver regardless of its scope. Only tests have the knowledge to manage the drone lifecycles. A page should just use whatever context it was invoked in. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

This may be the answer:

```
public class MyPage {

    @ArquillianResource
    private WebDriver driver;
```

But I'm afraid that this skips some Drone-specific enriching. Also not sure if it will correctly resolve when there are multiple Drone instances.